# issue in showing next image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i reffered this site http://jsfiddle.net/8FMsH/1/

//html

```
$(".rightArrow").on('click',function(){
imageClicked.closest('.images .os').next().find('img').trigger('click');
});
```

But its not moving to next image.the following is block contains and display image.

```
<div class="images">
<img class="os" id="1" src="http://labalec.fr/erwan/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ubuntu_large.jpeg" alt="ubuntu">
<img class="os" id="2" src="http://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/windows-8.1-start.jpg" alt="windows" >
</div>
<div class="overlay"> </div>
<div class="slideshow">
<img class="rightArrow" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7d/Aiga_rightarrow_inv.gif" alt="rightArrow" >
<img class="popup" src="" alt="clickedImage" >
</div>
```

please someone helps me

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: What error r u getting. Have u debugged it in browser

Comment: Have you put your code in a `document.ready` handler?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes i already did.. thanks for the reply

Comment: @Nitinvarpe how to debug in browser ?

Comment: @Nikhil thanks for the reply .. but i dont understand what you are saying?

Comment: In google chrome right click->inspect element->Sources and put breakpoint to function call for more chek this http://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/6478/how-to-debug-javascript-and-css-in-different-browsers/

Comment: I am saying do you see any js error in your browser console?

Comment: error in js:[17:51:02.693] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ file:///home/Bootstrap%20css/dist/slideshow.html

Comment: warning in css:[17:51:02.693] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ file:///home/Bootstrap%20css/dist/slideshow.html

Comment: warning in js:[17:51:13.001] Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. @ chrome://jquery/content/jquery-2.0.3.js:4923

Comment: I have no error. Next image is shown.

Comment: No error here either. Works as intended. What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pleas give all js,css, & js to review. If you are using only this js, it will not work. 
In given js there is lots of problems.

  imageClicked not defined.
  trigger('click') will only work if you define some functions with img selectors.
  ('.images .os').next().find('img') will not find anything.
```